# OCMVerifyAllWithDelay not working

Tags: objective-c, ocmock

I'm using `OCMock` to verify that some delegates methods are correctly called but it is not working even if I call them explicitly from my test code

```
id protocolMock = OCMProtocolMock(@protocol(NMARouteManagerDelegate));
sut.delegate = protocolMock;

[sut.delegate routeManager:sut skippedRouteForTransportMode:1];

OCMExpect([protocolMock routeManager:sut skippedRouteForTransportMode:1]);
OCMVerifyAllWithDelay(protocolMock, 1);
```

This fails with the error

> expected method was not invoked: routeManager: skippedRouteForTransportMode:1

It works fine though if I use a synchronous verification:

```
OCMVerify([protocolMock routeManager:sut skippedRouteForTransportMode:1]);
```

In my real test, I need the verification to be done asynchronously with `OCMVerifyAllWithDelay`

Comment: This may not be the issue, but you are setting the expectation after the method is called. What happens if you set the expectation before calling the method?

Comment: that was probably it, thanks